# Customise ListView (Multiple Choices)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to change the text color of a ListView with multiple choices. I found many questions about it, but most of the answers propose to create a TextView Layout and allocate it to the adapter as a solution. When I do that, the checkbox disappear.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

main_activity.xml

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this for other people having the same problem. I just modified Yaw Asare answer a little bit and it worked:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        TextView mytextview=(TextView)view;
        mytextview.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        mytextview.setTextSize(14);
        // Other code you may want to add

        return view;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the getView method in your arrayAdapter and set the text color like this.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = converteView; 
            if(v = null)
                v = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, null);

            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setTextColor("Your_color");

            return v;
        }
    };
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The text disappear. There is no error in the log and there is no text at all.